# Array as a class property

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to pass an array as a property of a custom class, but cannot find a way to do it, and didn't find a question already answered that worked for me. So here I am.

My 'movie' class has 4 properties as you can see below: titre, annee, duree and genres. The first 3 are working well, but I'am blocked on the last one. From a string, separated by commas, I need to create an array of the different genres of the movie (ie: adventure, action, etc). I can easily create this array, but cannot find a way to assign it as a movie.property.

The code below returns an incompatibility error. I probably have to implement a let property but don't understand how to do it... Does anyone has a clue of what I am doing wrong ? Tell me if you need a bigger sample of the code.

```
Public Sub initialiser(ByVal strLigne As String)
    Dim arrData
    arrData = Split(strLigne, vbTab)
    strtitre = arrData(0)
    strAnnee = arrData(1)
    intDuree = ConvertToInt(arrData(2))
    genres = CreerTabGenre(arrData(3))
 
End Sub
```

```
Property Get genre() As eGenre ' eGenre is an enum, and I have no choice about that (homework...)
    genre = genres() 'Here I tried all the combinations between parenthesis on both, on none, etc
End Property
```

edit: Maybe the problem is how I access the property after ? tabFilms is an array of all the different movies. As a test, I try to access the first genre of the array, but I'm met with 'incorrect affectation of property' error...

```
Function genrePopulaire(tabFilms() As film) As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(tabFilms)
        MsgBox tabFilms(i).genre(0)
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: `Property Get genre() As eGenre() `    and `genre=genres`

Comment: Same problem apparently...

Comment: If genres is an array you cannot pass it to a enumeration value which is what your current proerty is trying to do.  If you want to get a specific item from the genres array then your genre property get needs to specify an index.  e.g. Property Get genre(byval ipIndex as long) as as eGenre, genre=genres(ipIndex) end property.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your split array uses vbTab to split the string. And you said that they are separeted by commas. If so, you should add a comma at the end of the string. It would look like:

```
Lord of the Rings; 2002; 200; SciFi;
```

and use the split array like this:

arrData = split(strLigne, ";")

Also, I've tried this code working with class module.

Try this, on the module procedure:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Movie As Object
Set Movie = New clsMovie
Dim arrData

'strligne example
    Dim strligne As String
    strligne = "TLOTR" & vbTab & "2002" & vbTab & 200 & vbTab & "SciFi"

arrData = Split(strligne, vbTab)
With Movie
    .TestMovie arrData
'OUTPUT EXAMPLE:
    Debug.Print "Movie's name is " & .Titre & ". La duree est " & .Duree & " minutes and it was realised on " & .Annee & " and its genre is " & .Genre
End With
'you can change value at any time
movie.titre = "Harry Potter"
debug.print movie.titre & " " & movie.duree
End Sub
```

On the class Module (IMPORTANT: called clsMovie):

```
Option Explicit

'Declare all variables as private. If you want, instead of "Private" you can do it "Public" but it can be quite dangerous on a huge project. As you are declaring them Private, it's necessary to work with Let / Get statements below. 
Private pTitre As String, pAnnee As String, pDuree As String, pGenres As String
Function TestMovie(arr)
    Titre = arr(0)
    Annee = arr(1)
    Duree = arr(2)
    Genres = arr(3)
End Function
'From here to the end are the "Let / Get" properties as we work with private variables in the class
Property Get Titre() As String
    Titre = pTitre
End Property
Private Property Let Titre(value As String)
    pTitre = value
End Property
Property Get Annee() As String
    Annee = pAnnee
End Property
Property Let Annee(value As String)
    pAnnee = value
End Property
Property Get Duree() As String
    Duree = pDuree
End Property
Property Let Duree(value As String)
    pDuree = value
End Property
Property Get Genres() As String
    Genres = pGenres
End Property
Property Let Genres(value As String)
    pGenres = value
End Property
```